# Approving anonymous edits that change the initial question

Tags: discussion, editing

I saw the following questions edited by approving edits made by an anonymous user:

- https://sports.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/18740
- https://sports.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/18741

It is possible the changes were made by the OP as an anonymous user, but within two hours of this post, the [OP made a comment with his initial account](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/22542/men-vs-women-mma-fights#comment32365_22542).

Is this practice encouraged? I'm in favor of editing the question to narrow it down, but should we be doing this on the OP's behalf if it fundamentally changes the initial question or removes the initial intent?

In contrast, [my edit got rejected](https://sports.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/18737), though I was removing unrelated meta commentary. If removing "thank you" is appropriate, I'm not sure how removing mentions of porn isn't, especially as it bore no significance to the question itself.

Comment: Narrowing down a question is fine as long as the primary question stays as-is. That is why I rejected one of the edits. The primary question changed from *Does it exist?* to *Who wins?* and I believe this deviates too much from the original post. About your post I am not entirely sure, but I'd have rejected it as well. Sometimes it is good to know what to expect when searching for a particular sport or game. And when the search returns porn as a result it is a fact and not just meta commentary.

Comment: @dly Fair enough. Perhaps my SafeSearch filter is on, but [my Google search of the OP's title](https://www.google.com/search?q=men+vs.+women+mma+fights&rlz=1C1GCEU_enUS821US821&oq=men+vs.+women+mma+fights&aqs=chrome..69i57.2789j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) returned legitimate results that may lead to an answer. That said, I'm not repulsed by porn, but I'm sure we have a younger audience that utilizes this site. Saying the search results are not related is as descriptive as something that isn't related to sports.

Comment: @dly Moreover, my edit was rejected because it was deemed to change the original intent of the post (the same reason you rejected one of the edits). The reason I included my rejected edit here was because the anonymous edits may/may not have changed the original intent, but I have a hard time classifying my edit as having changed the intent (unless we focus on the part that isn't related to the question itself).

Comment: I see the reason and who did it, don't worry. But explaining the exact reason would be up to them. (And you suggested the edit with your account and not anonymously.) I can see the logic behind the rejection, but I can't tell for sure. You changed the search result info, which *may* be relevant to the asker and the reviewer, so the rejection is still legitimate. And IMHO the word porn alone is not really a problem for the younger audience.